# Is there a way to use template matching to detect changes in the input?

Tags: python, opencv, template-matching

I'm trying to use template matching to detect when the input from my screen no longer matches the template. The code below puts a rectangle around the area I want to detect a change in. Is there any way I can, lets say, print some text when that rectangle is no longer there?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
import pyautogui as gui
import glob

template_data=[]
files1 = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\aaaa\\template images\\template*.jpg")

for myfile in files1:
        image = cv2.imread(myfile,0)
        template_data.append(image)

while(True):
    source = ig.grab(bbox=(700,400,1200,700))
    screen_colour = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(source), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screen_colour), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    for tmp in template_data:
        (h, w) = tmp.shape[:2]
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(np.array(screen), tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        threshhold = 0.92
        loc = np.where(result >= threshhold)

        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            cv2.rectangle(screen, pt, (pt[0]+w, pt[1]+h), (0,255,255),2)
            print("yes")


    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

    cv2.imshow('Result',np.array(screen))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an offset, take the absolute difference of the template and the image and compare this to a threshold

```
def still_has_rect(template,image,pt):
    min_x = pt[0]
    max_x = min_x + template.shape[0]
    min_y = pt[1]
    max_y = min_y + template.shape[1]
    sub_image = image[min_x:max_x,min_y:max_y]

    difference = sum(abs(sub_image-template))
    return difference<threshold
```